# Access $event value in another function

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and javascript.

I'm getting a true or false value from this `(cellValueChanged)="enableCancelApplyButton($event)"`.

I want to use that value which i got from `enableCancelApplyButton($event)` in  `trashRowForDetailedEditFlowRules` function.

How can i do it ? Please help

```js
public trashRowForDetailedEditFlowRules(e: any) {
  let rowIndex = e.rowIndex;
  if (rowIndex == 1) {
    this.showDetailCancelFlag = true;
    this.showApplyButton = true;
  }

}

private enableCancelApplyButton(flag: boolean) {
  if (flag === true) {
    this.showDetailCancelFlag = false;
    this.showApplyButton = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<inline-edit-grid [gridParams]="editDetailGridParams" (cellValueChanged)="enableCancelApplyButton($event)" (rowClicked)="onDetailEditRowClicked($event)" (copyClicked)="onCopyClicked($event)" (trashClicked)="trashRowForDetailedEditFlowRules($event)" (editClicked)="editCellUpdate($event)"
  class="grid-top session-grid" #editDetailGrid>
</inline-edit-grid>
```

Comment: In what way do you want to use it? Do you need to call it on `(cellValueChanged)`?

Answer (score 0):

just a guess call trashRowForDetailedEditFlowRules inside enableCancelApplyButton and pass $event as a argument to trashRowForDetailedEditFlowRules(e).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's the better choice but you could easyly create a private property in which you can pass the value es:

```
private sharedBool: boolean = false;

    public trashRowForDetailedEditFlowRules(e: any) {
   //here you can access the sharedBool
  let rowIndex = e.rowIndex;
  if (rowIndex == 1) {
    this.showDetailCancelFlag = true;
    this.showApplyButton = true;
  }

}

private enableCancelApplyButton(event) {
  this.sharedBool = event;
  if (event === true) {
    this.showDetailCancelFlag = false;
    this.showApplyButton = false;
  }
}
```

Hope it can help